# how to add event listeners in jstree for check_node & uncheck_node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, event-listener

We are upgrading from jstree 1.x to 3.3.8. The old version had this:

```
$('#mytree').bind("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't fire in the new version. I tried changing to .on like this:

```
$('#mytree').on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
    ...
}
```

but that doesn't fire either.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mytree').on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
    ...
}
```

should work. Please check check_callback is set as true as below in your core config.

`"check_callback": true`

You can have a quick look at https://everyething.com/Example-of-jsTree-with-select-all-checkbox

This event is used there to check any of the node is unchecked so that "Select All" check box can be unticked.